# Xcode "move line" keyboard shortcut

Tags: xcode, xcode4, keyboard-shortcuts, key-bindings

In Xcode 4, I have been sucessfully able to add new custom keyboard shortcuts to move lines around or to duplicate a line:

**/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Frameworks/IDEKit.framework/Resources/IDETextKeyBindingSet.plist**

```
<key>My Custom Keys</key>
<dict>
    <key>Move Line Up</key>
    <string>selectLine:, cut:, moveUp:, moveToBeginningOfLine:, paste:, moveUp:</string>
    <key>Move Line Down</key>
    <string>selectLine:, cut:, moveDown:, moveToBeginningOfLine:, paste:, moveUp:</string>
    <key>Duplicate Line</key>
    <string>moveToBeginningOfLine:, deleteToEndOfLine:, yank:, insertNewline:, moveToBeginningOfLine:, yank:</string>
    <key>Delete Line</key>
    <string>selectLine:, delete:</string>
</dict>
```

But the **Move Line Up/Down** uses copy/paste, which I would like to avoid. Anyone knows how to move lines with *yank*, just like the **Duplicate Line** I found there: [Xcode duplicate line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10266170/xcode-4-duplicate-line/13369654#13369654)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Manipulating text in XCode, moving one line](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1380214/manipulating-text-in-xcode-moving-one-line) - one of the answers there has the official xcode 4 shortcut

Answer (score 169, accepted):

Copied from https://stackoverflow.com/a/9078952/852828 as that isn't the accepted answer to the linked duplicate.

> Xcode 4 has a new set of command for moving the line where the cursor is or the selected text with `command` + `option` + `[` or `]`
>
> `⌥⌘[` or `⌥⌘]`

Comment: For reference: the name of the commands are `Structure ▸ Move Line Up` and `Structure ▸ Move Line Down` in Key Bindings.

Comment: @gklka Thanks, this is what I was looking for (default key bindings usually don't work on foreign keyboard layouts, I had to change this one)

Comment: Thanks @gklka ! Your answer is still valid 8 years later 

Answer (score 16):

**How to move lines in Xcode via the menu OR hotkeys:**

[image]

**If you are using a Windows keyboard, the commands would translate to:**

- `⌥⌘[` ..... `Alt + Win + [`
- `⌥⌘]` ..... `Alt + Win + ]`